# How to script AT command to modem?

Tags: bash, scripting, devices, modem

Every time my USB modem (*/dev/dlinkModem*) gets unplugged it defaults to "radio disabled mode" (`AT+CFUN:4`).

I can easily enough call `AT+CFUN:1` through the `minicom` application console to enable radio again. However, I would of course like to make this an automated task as it sits on my server.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://manpages.debian.org/ppp/chat.8.en.html

Comment: Perect! Thank you. cant accept a comment as an answer tho :)

Comment: make it work (it's usually called from pppd but doesn't have to) and write the answer yourself on how you made it work for your case.

Comment: I think expect(1) was designed for this.